# iPhone doesn't scroll on div with higher z-index

Tags: iphone, css, scroll, z-index

I've created a `div` that lays on top of the body with a higher `z-index`. When I try to scroll the content on the `div` it just scrolls the body content in the background. Can someone please explain this phenomenon? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use two-fingered scrolling to navigate divs with scrollbars on iOS devices.

**[Update]** Reference: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1484

Comment: The provided link is dead. Also two-fingered scrolling seems really counter-intuitive. Is there any possible workaround?